# PhoneGap: Angular controllers don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have an HTML single-page web app that I'm trying to turn into a PhoneGap application for Windows Phone 8.

The app uses Angular and jQuery Mobile, and to get to two cooperating, I had to use the [jquery-mobile-angular-adapter](https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter). The application works fine in all browsers, including IE 10 mobile on the Nokia Lumia Windows Phone.

When I compile and test as a PhoneGap application on the device, the various libraries seem to load and initialize fine until they get to an Angular controller. Controllers never load/initialize, no matter how simple they are.

Here's how the libraries load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter-standalone-1.3.1.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('DEVICE READY - ANGULAR DOCUMENT READY');
      angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['psxclient']);
    });
  }, false);
</script>  
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.metro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.metro.mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/vendor/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/filters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and here's some simple code that mimics my Angular, where everything initializes and the `console.log` traces work, minus the controller's `'APPCTRL'`:

```
var psxclient = angular.module('psxclient', ['stubdata', 'common-filters']).
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    console.log('APP');
        $routeProvider.when('/deal/:id', 
             {
                templateUrl: '#deal',
                jqmOptions: { transition: 'slide' }
        });
    console.log('CONFIG COMPLETE');
    }).controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $history, $location)
    {
    console.log('APPCTRL');
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the cut-and-paste typo. That wasn't the case in my app, so issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

I think in $routeProvider, there is no any command to call the `AppCtrl` controller to run.
I'm not confident with my answer, because if with this cause, `AppCtrl` should not be able to work in web browser neither. But it worth to try, change the $routeProvider to following code.

```
 $routeProvider.when('/deal/:id', 
 {
            templateUrl: '#deal',
            jqmOptions: { transition: 'slide' },
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
 });
```

Moreover, does the 'DEVICE READY - ANGULAR DOCUMENT READY' was shown up?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, adding the controllers to the routes didn't help. The controllers in my HTML are just attached to divs that are all in the same page. And yep, the 'DEVICE READY - ANGULAR DOCUMENT READY' console.log fires and the bootstrap call after it seems to partially work, since some of the code in the angular.module runs. Just not the controllers.

Comment: Well, as it turns out, it occasionally fails before getting to configuring route providers. If I omit the dependencies from the app module (stubdata, common-filters), it at least gets the routeProvider configuration done reliably.